# Looping in MySQL to create a concatenated variable

Tags: mysql, wordpress, metadata

I have a Wordpress site which has post ratings stored in the wp_ratings table, with each rating stored as an individual row. We will be changing the theme soon and need to convert the values stored in wp_ratings to meta data, which will look as follows:

```
a: 3: {
i: 0;
a: 2: {
    s: 7: "user_id";
    s: 1: "0";
    s: 2: "ip";
    s: 9: "127.0.0.1";
}
i: 1;
a: 2 {
    s: 7: "user_id";
    s: 1: "0";
    s: 2: "ip";
    s: 9: "127.0.0.1";
}
i: 2;
a: 2: {
    s: 7: "user_id";
    s: 1: "0";
    s: 2: "ip";
    s: 9: "127.0.0.1";
}
i: 3;
a: 2: {
    s: 7: "user_id";
    s: 1: "0";
    s: 2: "ip";
    s: 9: "127.0.0.1";
}
```

The total vote value is show by the `a:3` at the beginning of the statement and then there is an individual entry for each rating stored.

I am not particularly familiar with stored procedures but I want to create a loop that will calculate the total value for each post in wp_posts `sum(rating_rating)` and then create the meta data into one long string.

I don't really know where to start with this, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: There's a semi-colon missing on line 10.  

(I don't have enough privileges to correct it.)   

The first brace opened is never closed.  This leaves solutions open to ambiguity!

Comment: The first brace encompasses all the individual entries within it. The closing brace should be at the every end of the statement.

Comment: Are you saying the first brace doesn't need to be closed (because it's not)?  Can you post the meta data specs?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a meta data spec per se, but this forum thread should explains how it works. http://cosmothemes.com/forums/topic/436

Comment: Also jonlester, yes, the first brace should be closed - I left it out in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setup test data

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ratings` ( 
  `rating_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `rating_postid` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_posttitle` TEXT NOT NULL, 
  `rating_rating` INT(2) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_timestamp` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_ip` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_host` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  `rating_userid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rating_id`), 
  KEY `rating_postid` (`rating_postid`) 
); 

INSERT INTO `test`.`wp_ratings` 
  (`rating_id`, `rating_postid`, `rating_posttitle`, 
  `rating_rating`, `rating_timestamp`, `rating_ip`, 
  `rating_host`, `rating_username`, `rating_userid`)
  VALUES
  (1,1,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1),
  (2,2,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1),
  (3,2,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1),
  (4,3,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1),
  (5,3,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1),
  (6,3,'title',1,'abc','127.0.0.1','a.a.a','user_id',1);
```

---

### Query

```
SET @post_id = 3;

SELECT CONCAT
(
'a:', COUNT(rating_id), ':{',
    (
        SELECT CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(meta_data_vote SEPARATOR ''), '}') FROM
        (
            SELECT CONCAT
            ( 
                'i:',
                @curRow := @curRow + 1,
                ';a:2:{s:7:"', 
                rating_username, 
                '";s:1:"0";s:2:"ip";s:9:"', 
                rating_ip,
                '";}'
            )AS meta_data_vote
            FROM
                wp_ratings
            JOIN (SELECT @curRow := -1 AS j) r
            WHERE rating_postid = @post_id
        )AS meta_data_votes
    )
) AS new_ratings_meta_data
FROM wp_ratings l
WHERE rating_postid = @post_id
```

---

### Result (where @post_id = 3)

```
a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"0";s:2:"ip";s:9:"127.0.0.1";}i:1;a:2:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"0";s:2:"ip";s:9:"127.0.0.1";}i:2;a:2:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"0";s:2:"ip";s:9:"127.0.0.1";}}
```

---

### Conclusion

I haven't been able to write a query that returns a resultset with post_ids and their new meta_data.

The above code will only convert on a post-by-post basis.

If you want to batch update, it'll need more thought, but i think this will get you off to a good start.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks, this is brilliant.

One problem though - there are some posts that have been rated more than 1500 times, so the approximate length of the meta data for those posts may be around 90,000 characters. This solution works where there are very few votes, so how do I get the query to the strings in their entirety?

Comment: When I run the query in MySQL Workbench it just returns the string as 'BLOB' and in Sequel Pro it gets as far as the fourth vote and then goes no further. Don't know if this is just a display limit or not. Might try inserting the value into another table to see if it returns the complete string.

Comment: @Andy, try: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Comment: perfect! one final problem - I have tweaked it to show the results grouped by post_id and want to import this into the 'wp_postmeta' table, but when I use an insert select statement, I get an error. Will post the query below:

Comment: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ('post_id','meta_key','meta_value')
SELECT
rating_postid 
,'like'
,CONCAT
(
'a:', sum(rating_rating), ':{',
    (
        SELECT CONCAT( GROUP_CONCAT(meta_data_vote SEPARATOR ''), '}') FROM
        (
            SELECT CONCAT
            ( 
                'i:',
                @curRow := @curRow + 1,
                ';a:2:{s:7:"', 
                'user_id', 
                '";s:1:"0";s:2:"ip";s:16:"', 
                '-127-000-000-001',
                '";}'
            )AS meta_data_vote`

Comment: `FROM
                wp_ratings
                ,wp_posts p
            JOIN (SELECT @curRow := -1 AS j) r
            WHERE rating_postid = p.ID
             and rating_rating >0
             AND p.post_type = 'post'
   GROUP BY rating_postid
        )AS meta_data_votes
    )
) AS new_ratings_meta_data
FROM wp_ratings l
,wp_posts p
WHERE rating_postid = p.ID
and rating_rating >0
AND p.post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY rating_postid`

Comment: swap:     ('post_id','meta_key','meta_value')  so it reads:     (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) - you have to use backticks for field names.  When i put them in the comment it made them into code and didn't convey the point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about stored procedures, but I think you can do this with just a single query instead, using group_concat() and group by post id.

Comment: Would that work? the 'i' value at the beginning of each individual rating doesn't exist within the database at the moment, so I think would require a variable used as a counter...?

Comment: No, use the COUNT(*) function an it will return the number if rows grouped together.

Comment: You can literally write COUNT(*) in your query.